# How can I add a button to the empty area of a TabControl in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, tabcontrol

Grabbed the images from a similar question in WPF. Basically I want the extra buttons to do different things, not create or delete tabs. Actions related to the current tab which are gonna be the same for all the tabs in a single TabControl.

When I try to place my buttons on that area, the visual studio designer throws my control away, back to their original position. It doesn't allow me to put anything there.

Can this be done?

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/92ca1b0a8c.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/92ca1b0a8c.png)

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ff0d08e0ed.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ff0d08e0ed.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For specifically that visual experience I'd just create a separate tab with header "+" and add some logic on switching to it - so it will perform some other action instead of switching. The same can be done with multiple tabs I guess.

**UPDATE**

Actual code for this:

```
private void TabControl1_Selecting(Object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.TabPage... /* Do check whether some of your special TabPages is being selected */)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        // All other TabPage-specific actions here
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what event would you suggest for this? It will not switch to it or anything though, right? Otherwise the user would realize the hack.

Comment: `TabControl.Selecting` - you may cancel page change using this event. More info - http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selecting.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like they are using a tab as a button here.  I would imagine they have the tab controls index change event fire a new tab into the tab control and force focus to it.